# Why does Mariadb fail to run, claiming the redo log is ancient if I have been running a newer version for a long time?

Tags: mariadb, innodb, recovery

After a power outage, my Mariadb 10.5.10 server fails to start, saying this:

```
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.5.10-MariaDB) starting as process 1260999 ...
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Aria engine: log initialization failed
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE4.2 crc32 instructions
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. This redo log was created before MariaDB 10.2.2, and we did not find a valid checkpoint. Please follow the instructions at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/upgrading/
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
Jun 23 17:35:38 heater mysqld[1260999]: 2023-06-23 17:35:38 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I'm baffled by the reference to "before 10.2.2" because I've been running 10.5.10 for quite some time.

How do I recover? Going back to 10.2.2 seems unlikely to work?

`--innodb-force-recovery=` until level 2 makes no difference, haven't tried anything higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that I ended up with some bad disk-level corruption that mariadb could not recover from :-(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Did you identify a cause? What should people look for to identify that disk level corruption occurred?

Answer (score 0):

> I've been running 10.5.10 for quite some time

Are you 100% sure? The redo log message is pretty accurate. Could you have upgraded at some point and the old < 10.2.2 process was still running?

> Going back to 10.2.2 seems unlikely to work

Actually it is. With a container is possible to do without removing the 10.5 packages.

`docker run -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:z --name m101 --rm mariadb:10.1`

After its recovered and started up;

`docker exec m101 mysql -u root -ppass -e 'shutdown'`.

Then start in 10.5 again.

Also check [MDEV-18532](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18532).